# Missing contract in WCF self hosted console application

Tags: c#, wcf

Trying to make simple selfhosted WCF service in console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SupportSrvWCF
{


    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IA
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int LogIt(int id, string data, ref int level);
    }


    public class SupportServicee : IA
    {
        public int LogIt(int id, string data, ref int level)
        {

            return 0;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SupportServicee));
                selfHost.Open();



                Console.WriteLine("The service is running. Press any key to stop.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>



  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>


      <service name="SupportSrvWCF.SupportServicee">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SupportSrvWCF.IA ">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8002/WCFService1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>




    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <!--<behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>-->
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Have exception:

```
An error occurred: 'System.InvalidOperationException: The contract name 'Support
SrvWCF.IA ' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the servi
ce 'SupportServicee'.
```

Where is problem

Answer (score 0):

hello try the following code instead and delete the service configuration from app.config

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace SupportSrvWCF
{


    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IA
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int LogIt(int id, string data, ref int level);
    }


    public class SupportServicee : IA
    {
        public int LogIt(int id, string data, ref int level)
        {

            return 0;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SupportServicee),new Uri("http://localhost:8080/Myservice"))) 
            {
                try
                {
                    selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IA),new BasicHttpBinding(),"basic");

                    selfHost.Open();



                    Console.WriteLine("The service is running. Press any key to stop.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but I would like to know what is wrong with my configuration

Comment: The probleme is in this line

 <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SupportSrvWCF.IA ">

you need to remove the space in contract="SupportSrvWCF.IA " and make it contract="SupportSrvWCF.IA" that is all